# What's the difference between "for x in file/file.readlines()"

Tags: python, file-io, readlines

According to the type, file is a function and file.readlines() is a list of lines. But why do these two generate the same results in the following code:

```
file = open("test.txt")
for x in file:
    print x
```

and

```
file = open("test.txt")
for x in file.readlines():
    print x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readlines()` reads the entire file into a `list()`, over which you then iterate using `for`. But, you can also just iterate over the `file` object itself, which will cause it to read one line at a time with each iteration of the loop. That's much more efficient, since it won't store the entire file's contents in memory at once.